# Tax category in germany when paying for girlfriend rent/education (not married)

Tags: taxes, germany

I am going to care of my partner during the time she does her master. She's persian and will do her master in Germany.

I'll basically be responsible to pay for life costs, universities etc.

I know one can change tax class when married or with a civil union (which only works for same sex people, which we aren't). Is there another way that I don't know to do it or am I blocked?

Comment: Is it too late to get married?

Comment: I don't know when it is but she'll come for next summer summester

Comment: @MichaelKaras AFAIK in Germany getting married on Dec 31st will earn you the tax benefits for the entire year, so it is almost never too late...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but if you are not married, you are each in tax class 1 (single). Any cost that you have could only be deductible if there is a legal obligation, for example you might have a legal obligation if she were your ex-wife, or your mother or daughter.